# URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate problems

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession

Ever since I upgraded to Swift 3 I've ran into problems with loading information from the backend. Before Swift 3 I was using:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (response, data, error) in

     if let responseData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
         print("data: \(responseData)")
         self.parseXML(data!)        
     }
}
```

But after I updated, every time I would run I would get the error that the server is invalid and a server may be pretending to be it.

After looking through stackoverflow I changed my code to:

```
let task = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
task.dataTask(with: request).resume()
```

The request itself hasn't changed:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "urlhere")!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("**authentication**", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.httpBody = "req=\(xmlRequest)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

My class is implementing the `URLSessionDelegate` and `URLSessionData` delegates

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    print("Data received: \(data)")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

    print("Response received: \(response)")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    print("something went wrong!")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    print("did autherntcationchallenge = \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust  {
        print("send credential Server Trust")
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        challenge.sender!.use(credential, for: challenge)

    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic{
        print("send credential HTTP Basic")
        let defaultCredentials: URLCredential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence:URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender!.use(defaultCredentials, for: challenge)

    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM{
        print("send credential NTLM")

    } else{
        challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandling!(for: challenge)
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
    print("there was an error: \(error)")
}
```

However, when I run now, the did receive challenge function is executed but none of the others are, I've tested this using print statements and using breakpoints.

Here is my console:

> did autherntcationchallenge = NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
>   send credential Server Trust

This is the only thing printed, so none of the other functions are called. What's going wrong here?

*****Edit*****

So after more testing I realized that if I comment out the receive challenge function the did complete with error function is called,
So, they are indeed called but when the receive challenge is called none of the other functions are run, and therefore, I cannot get any data from my server.

Answer (score 0):

This code is *dangerous*.  You're completely disabling all TLS validation by doing what you're doing, which makes your connections no better than HTTP.  You should never just blindly accept the certificate provided by the server.

Instead, check it first to make sure it is actually yours, *then* do what you did above, or if it isn't perform default handling so that the request will fail.

Additionally, one of the certs in your chain is expired, and you're making a request by IP address, which is one reason why your certificate validation fails.  Don't do that.  Use a domain name with a real certificate.  You can get free certs from any number of authorities, so there's really no excuse for not having a valid certificate on your server.

Finally, your server is using an outdated cipher, EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA, which uses 3DES.  You should be moving away from that cipher, as it will likely become unsupported in a future version of iOS.

As for why the request isn't continuing to execute, I don't know.  There's probably something wrong in your upgraded Swift syntax, but that's outside my area of expertise, so I won't attempt to guess what it is.  But IMO, that's largely moot, because you shouldn't be doing what you're doing, and if you weren't trying to effectively disable TLS, that code wouldn't exist, and your app would work.  :-)